# Angular async pipe and object property

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I need to use async pipe without ngFor. I need to check property of object that is async loaded with observable.

This is what i want, but not working:

```
 <ion-item *ngIf="user$.anonymouse | async">
     <ion-label>Login</ion-label>
 </ion-item>
```

//EDIT: I getting this error when i use code above

> EXCEPTION: Invalid argument 'true' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' in [!user$.anonymouse | async in SettingsPage@27:22]

Is there any way how to solve this?

I know i can subscribe to this observable in Ctrl a store values into normal variable but i dont want to do that, because of perfomance etc.

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/AsyncPipe-class.html the asyncPipe doesn't require ngFor.

Comment: I getting error if i use code above, i added error to question.

Comment: @DavidL As of now (2.0+) it works. :)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The error is surprisingly accurate as the `*ngIf` directive expects `true` or `false` and uses the resulting expression to determine whether or not to render the `HTML` element in the DOM.

> EXCEPTION: Invalid argument 'true' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' in [!user$.anonymouse | async in SettingsPage@27:22]

The expression you have is `user$.anonymouse` which evaluates as truthy, but unfortunately you cannot use the `async` pipe with this directive. The `async` pipe "transforms" (also known as "pipes") the input exposing the resulting output within the scope of the `*ngFor` directive for example.

The pipe expects one of three possible types, defined below ([detailed about AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html)):

`transform(obj: Observable<any>| Promise<any>| EventEmitter<any>)`

> Is there any way how to solve this?

Yes, you can either use it as it was designed. For example in an `*ngFor` directive:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="(user$ | async)?.anonymouse">
     <ion-label>Login</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Need to clarify the use of AsyncPipe with NgFor as discussed above. The expression `*ngFor="user$.anonymouse | async"` will pass the `anonymouse` property of `user$` to AsyncPipe, which I believe would be `undefined` because `user$` is an observable, not the output of the observable.
In order to run AsyncPipe on `user$` and then access the `anonymouse` property on the result, you would need to use `*ngFor="(user$ | async)?.anonymouse"`.

Comment: I think the comment by @Sean should be an answer and marked as the accepted answer. The accepted answer gives a nice explanation; however, as pointed out by Sean, `(user$ | async)?.anonymouse` is what the OP needs to do (and what worked for me! Thanks!)

Comment: The second approach does definetely not work as user$ is an Observable and has not mentioned property. Thats why people try to use obervables in *ngIf statements.

Answer (score 71):

As stated in the comments by @Sean, your `*ngIf` statement should be based on the resulted object property `anonymouse` of the `user$` object that is returned. As such:

```
<ion-item *ngIf="(user$ | async)?.anonymouse">
     <ion-label>Login</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

This worked for me and here is an example of how to use the results from the pipe below:

### Component

```
 message$: Observable<{message: string}>;

  private messages = [
    {message: 'You are my hero!'},
    {message: 'You are the best hero!'},
    {message: 'Will you be my hero?'}
  ];

  constructor() { this.resend(); }

  resend() {
    this.message$ = Observable.interval(500)
      .map(i => this.messages[i])
      .take(this.messages.length);
  }
```

### View

```
<h2>Async Hero Message and AsyncPipe</h2>
<p>Message: {{ (message$ | async)?.message }}</p>
<button (click)="resend()">Resend</button>`
```

A working example can be found [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/cjAY2eUaXkh9goB6kDpg/).

Answer (score 44):

```html
<!-- This is needed to wait for async pipe to resolve -->
<div *ngIf="user$ | async as user"> 

   <!-- Only on resolve of async pipe -->
   <ion-item *ngIf="user.whateverPropertyYouWantToCheck">
        <ion-label>Login</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
</div>
```

Please note that I switched from `user$` to `user`, you can use the same variable name if you want to, but this makes it more clear that the value is no longer an async pipe.

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion.

Comment: Yep, That's better than `*ngIf="(user$ | async)?.anonymouse"`

Answer (score 0):

isAnonymouse$ = user$.pipe(map(user => user?.anonymouse));

```
<ion-item *ngIf="user$.anonymouse | async">
```