# how to use async inside html

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

How can I include async here in this code for user?

```html
<div *ngIf="usersService.loaded$ | async">
<nb-card>
  <nb-card-header>
    <h1> {{ user?.name }} | {{ user?.age }} </h1>
  </nb-card-header>
</nb-card>
```

The user is being initiated as follows using a method from the store:

```js
    this.user = this.route.params
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
        switchMap(({ userId }) => this.usersService.getSelectedUser(userId))
      );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular async pipe and object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142196/angular-async-pipe-and-object-property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
<div *ngIf="usersService.loaded$ | async">
    <nb-card>
        <nb-card-header>
            <ng-container *ngIf="user | async as usr; else notFound">
                <h1>{{usr.name}} | {{usr.age}}</h1>
            </ng-container>
        </nb-card-header>
    </nb-card>
</div>
<ng-template #notFound>
    <div class="error">could not locate the user</div>
</ng-template>
```

If you want to use the user in other parts of the card, you can move the `*ngIf="user | async as usr"` to the `<nb-card>` element.  That way the user would be available in any card content.

```
<div *ngIf="usersService.loaded$ | async">
    <nb-card *ngIf="user | async as usr; else notFound">
        <nb-card-header>
            <h1>{{usr.name}} | {{usr.age}}</h1>
        </nb-card-header>
        <nb-card-content>
           {{usr.bio}}
        <nb-card-content>
    </nb-card>
</div>
<ng-template #notFound>
    <div class="error">could not locate the user</div>
</ng-template>
```

In the two cases above, if the user observable's value is null, then the *ngIf will fail.  In some cases, you may want to use a default value when the user is null.  I have been using this little trick that I probably learned somewhere on SO :)

```
<div *ngIf="usersService.loaded$ | async">
    <nb-card *ngIf="{usr: user | async} as obs">
        <nb-card-header>
            <h1>{{obs.usr?.name || 'Jane Doe'}} | {{obs.usr?.age || '100'}}</h1>
        </nb-card-header>
        <nb-card-content>
           {{obs.usr?.bio || 'Very Famous'}}
        <nb-card-content>
    </nb-card>
</div>
```

Actually, I would probably join the two observables like this...

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{loaded: usersService.loaded$ | async, usr: user | async} as obs">
    <div *ngIf="obs.loaded">
      <nb-card>
          <nb-card-header>
              <h1>{{obs.usr?.name || 'Jane Doe'}} | {{obs.usr?.age || '100'}}</h1>
          </nb-card-header>
          <nb-card-content>
            {{obs.usr?.bio || 'Very Famous'}}
          <nb-card-content>
      </nb-card>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just surround the async pipe call with brackets:

```html
<div *ngIf="usersService.loaded$ | async">
  <nb-card>
    <nb-card-header>
      <h1>{{ (user | async)?.name }} | {{ (user | async)?.age }}</h1>
    </nb-card-header>
  </nb-card>
</div>
```